# How to select 1 row per id?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with a table that has multiple rows for each order id (e.g. variations in spelling for addresses and different last_updated dates), that in theory shouldn't be there (not my doing). I want to select just 1 row for each id and so far I figured I can do that using partitioning like so:

```
SELECT dp.order_id, 
       MAX(cr.updated_at) OVER(PARTITION BY dp.order_id) AS updated_at
```

but I have seen other queries which only use MAX and list every other column like so

```
SELECT dp.order_id, 
       MAX(dp.ship_address) as address, 
       MAX(cr.updated_at) as updated_at
```

etc...

this solution looks more neat but I can't get it to work (still returns multiple rows per single order_id). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is the rest of the query? Seems that you join two tables. Which columns are listed next to the GROUP BY clause ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one row per `order_id`, then window functions are not sufficient.  They don't filter the data.  You seem to want the most recent row.  A typical method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by order_id order by created_at desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can also use aggregation:

```
select order_id, max(ship_address), max(created_at)
from t
group by order_id;
```

However, the `ship_address` may not be from the most recent row and that is usually not desirable.  You can tweak this using `keep` syntax:

```
select order_id,
       max(ship_address) keep (dense_rank first order by created_at desc),
       max(created_at)
from t
group by order_id;
```

However, this gets cumbersome for a lot of columns.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd "solution" doesn't care about values in other columns - it selects their MAX values. It means that you'd get `ORDER_ID` and - possibly - "mixed" values for other columns, i.e. those `ADDRESS` and `UPDATED_AT` might belong to different rows.

If that's OK with you, then go for it. Otherwise, you'll have to select **one** MAX row (using e.g. `row_number` analytic function), and fetch data that is related only to it (i.e. doesn't "mix" values from different rows).

---

Also, saying that you

> can't get it to work (still returns multiple rows per single order_id)

is kind of difficult to believe. The way you put it, it can't be true.